# Can we use a simple future noun clause in a present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, future-constructions

I want to say that my friend and I will not know something happens **until** tomorrow. Can I say:

> We haven't known *what will happen*. [1]

Somebody told me that a clause is a noun clause when I can substitute the clause with a noun. The italicized clause above, I assume, that's a clause that has future tense construction since it uses *will*.

However, now let's focus on my title and the quoted sentence above. Somehow, it seems to be incorrect if I mix two different tenses at the same time (I just feel that's wrong, I don't know why). Can you tell me whether my sentence above is legal? Perhaps people would suggest saying:

> We don't know what will happen.[2]

but as I have mentioned above that we will know something in the future for sure, we just don't know at this time, but we will. I sense different meanings in those two sentences: [1] and [2].

Comment: The Present Perfect in *We **haven't known** what will happen* has its usual implication - the state/activity of "not knowing what will happen" started at some time in the past, and has continued right up until time of speaking. The construction is generally ambiguous as to whether that past state continues through the present moment into the future, OR has just ended, OR is just *about* to end (i.e. - it's unspecified whether we ***now*** know what will happen - or indeed whether we'll ***ever*** know the future).

Comment: **We haven't known what would happen**. Also.